# add a shade from red to the div background

Tags: jquery

I have a div with white background, and I'd like to apply a progressive shade (in 600ms) to it from red to its white background.

I think .fadeOut() is the solution, but I don't know how to set red as beginning color.

Comment: the background color is black but you want to start from red? ..there would be a sudden jump to red. won't look good IMO.

Comment: lol! I wrong color... I mean white heheh! Question Edited ;)

Comment: What is a "classic div"?

Comment: nEEbz's point still applies, just replacing 'black' with 'white'.

Comment: A div, without any special effect to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this(uses jquery-ui):

```
$(function(){
    $("#divID").css({backgroundColor:"#F00" });
    $("#divID").animate({
        backgroundColor:"#000" 
        }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: according to the docs, backgroundColor cannot be animated ref: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: It's a fairly common plugin to have installed, I think he made that assumption

Comment: that only works with the plugin or jQuery UI. Try unchecking "jQuery UI 1.8.9" on your fiddle and it'll fail.

Comment: @Ben: Yes it does. If its confusing, then I should put a note in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$("selector").css("backgroundColor", "red").fadeOut()`

Comment: It works, but in fact I wrong to put the question! I need a fadeIn() in fact, that start from red to the background color...

Answer (score 0):

Install: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Then:

```
$("#myDivId").animate({backgroundColor: "#fff"}, 600);
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gAqGL/

and here's the code:

```
$( "#yourDiv" ).css('background-color', '#FF0000).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#000000",
    color: "#fff",
    width: 500
}, 600 );
```

as per your edit:  swap #000000 with #FFFFFF;